# Mongod 2.4 not running Fedora 19 freeze

Tags: mongodb, installation, fedora

The problem:
Repo installed as shown in official GUide [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/#install-mongodb)

After starting mongod there is freeze:

```
service mongod start
Starting mongod (via systemctl):
```

And it stops like this

Adding log info

```
cat /var/log/mongo/mongod.log

Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.431 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=32320 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=SLI.DOMnet
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.431 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.431 [initandlisten] git version: b9925db5eac369d77a3a5f5d98a145eaaacd9673
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.431 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.431 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.431 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongo", fork: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongo/mongod.log", pidfilepath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.444 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongo/journal
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.444 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.458 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Tue Sep  3 14:03:40.458 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Running proceses:

```
ps aux | grep mongo
root      5023  0.0  0.0 112664   932 pts/3    S+   14:06   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo
root     32258  0.0  0.0 113280  1548 pts/0    S+   14:03   0:00 /bin/sh /sbin/service mongod start
root     32304  0.0  0.0 115384  1516 pts/0    S+   14:03   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/mongod start
root     32310  0.0  0.0 132988  1192 pts/0    S+   14:03   0:00 /bin/systemctl start mongod.service
mongod   32320  0.2  0.2 451772 33772 ?        Sl   14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

I can run `mongo` on other terminal but this terminal is freezed and after a longer time I get:

```
 service mongod start
Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed. See 'systemctl status mongod.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.                                                          
                                                           [FAILED]
```

And then the proceses are like:

```
ps aux | grep mongo
root     15787  0.0  0.0 112664   928 pts/3    S+   14:10   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo
mongod   32320  0.2  0.2 452800 34316 ?        Sl   14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

But still can use `mongo` console. What about that `failed` part ?

```
journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at sob 2013-07-27 13:53:59 CEST, end at wto 2013-09-03 14:08:40 CEST. --
wrz 03 14:03:40  mongod[32312]: Starting mongod: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
wrz 03 14:03:40  mongod[32312]: forked process: 32320
wrz 03 14:03:40  mongod[32312]: all output going to: /var/log/mongo/mongod.log
wrz 03 14:03:40  mongod[32312]: child process started successfully, parent exiting
wrz 03 14:03:40  runuser[32316]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
wrz 03 14:03:40  mongod[32312]: [  OK  ]
wrz 03 14:03:40  systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/mongo/mongod.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
wrz 03 14:08:40  systemd[1]: mongod.service operation timed out. Terminating.
wrz 03 14:08:40  systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/catalog/be02cf6855d2428ba40df7e9d022f03d
-- 
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
wrz 03 14:08:40 SLI.DOMnet systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: looks like you start mongod process okay, then you try to start it again which expected fails (it's already running).  when you connect with shell it's now connecting to the original mongod process which is still running.  No?

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers already state, the problem is the `mongod.pid` file which systemd expects elsewhere. Until the package is fixed, I found the best way to solve this, was to change the mongod configuration to create the `.pid` file in `/var/mongo` (the other possibility would be to update the systemd unit file).

First, create `/var/mongo`:

```
mkdir /var/mongo
chown mongod /var/mongo
chgrp mongod /var/mongo
```

Edit `/etc/mongod.conf` and update like this:

```
# location of pidfile
pidfilepath = /var/run/mongo/mongod.pid
```

Make sure `mongod` is not running  and now it should be able to start it using systemctl:

```
systemctl start mongod
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug. It is the MOngoDB rpm fault. Mongo is looking for `/var/run/mongo/mongod.pid` and the path is `/var/run/mongodb/mongodb.pid`. Hope they will fix this. As for now no fix for this in fedora 18/19.

Answer (score 0):

As mSc said above

> I found the bug. It is the MOngoDB rpm fault. Mongo is looking for >/var/run/mongo/mongod.pid and the path is /vat/run/mongodb/mongodb.pid. Hope they >will fix this. As for now no fix for this in fedora 18/19

So you can create `/var/run/mongo` directory and copy `mongodb.pid` to it as root:

```
mkdir /var/run/mongo   
cp /var/run/mongodb/mongodb.pid /var/run/mongo/
```

I tried and can run mongodb in fedora 19